# Is there a way to requeue a delayed job task if a condition isn't met?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, delayed-job

I'd like to only allow a task to be run if a user is confirmed. I think that the thing to do might be to throw an exception and have the delayed_job stack requeue the task, but I don't know if this is abusing that feature.

Given that, is there a proper way to requeue a task if a condition, such as user confirmation, has not yet been met?

Answer (score 1):

There is no right answer to this and it really depends on what are you trying to achieve.  A batch process (delayed job) is usually meant to process mundane tasks without any (or lesser) human intervention.  Before you choose "a" strategy, you might want to figure out certain things:

1) How critical is it for your job to process all entities without failure?

2) How inconvenient is your user's experience going to be?

3) How important is it for this process to be completely autonomous?

If your answer is highly critical/important for any of these three questions, you might want to go for strategy #1 below.  If the failure is tolerable, go for #2.  Finally, if you can leave it upto the humans to work on failed entities, go for #3.

1) have your delayed job, create a failure queue, push the failed objects in there and retry after a certain time period.

2) just plain neglect the failure, assuming the data will be fixed the following day before the job runs again.

3) let your job report any failures to you (or the system admin), so you can interfere and try to assuage the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm going to go with #2, and see what the hit rate is to figure out if I have to go with #1

Answer (score -1):

I think the solution would be to `forcefully fail` the job which you want to re-queue until your condition is met.

To force fail you can do something like `Delayed::Job.find_by_id(id).last`. This condition will always fail as `find_by_id` method will fetch a single record. You can replace `id` with anything else. Your goal is to fail that job anyway.